# Create Ribbon in WPF App with with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, ribbon

I've created a new WPF App in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows Classic Desktop on Windows 10.

I add the ribbon to new application in following way.
The xaml code:

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="AKnowledgeBase.MainWindow"
        xmlns:r1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AKnowledgeBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
                xmlns:r2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
                Title="AKnowledgeBase" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <r:Ribbon>
            <r2:RibbonTabsPanel></r2:RibbonTabsPanel>
        </r:Ribbon>

    </DockPanel>

</r:RibbonWindow>
```

And change the base class:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

But the result application window looks ugly:

[image]

On the image above you can see the Explorer caption (it have standard view in Windows10) and the created application caption (it looks like Windows98-styled view).

Why it happens and how it could be fixed?

**UPD1**:

When I use suggested below reference to the System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll the main window have blue artifacts on left and righ sides:
[image]

Also when I maximize this window - there are appears bug with caption:

[image]

The text partitially cut.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll` and try this XAML markup:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="AKnowledgeBase.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:r2="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window14" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Ribbon>
                <r2:RibbonTabsPanel></r2:RibbonTabsPanel>
            </Ribbon>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

You probably don't need the `RibbonWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="AKnowledgeBase.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        xmlns:r2="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window14" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Ribbon>
                <r2:RibbonTabsPanel></r2:RibbonTabsPanel>
            </Ribbon>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: 1) About you first suggestion - look at the update in first post

Comment: Which update? You shouldn't use RibbonControlsLibrary.dll.

Comment: 2) About "you probably dont need the RibbonWindow" - but I need it becase if I use usual Window - there are appears 2 captions: first - usual window caption, second - "ribbon caption" where it could draw some controls.

Comment: Set the WindowStyle property to None or create your own custom window template.

Comment: 1) Yes, I remove all references and use only System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll ;  2) If I set WindowStyle to None - I cant close/move/minimize.. etc. As I understand correctly the Ribbon caption must somehow overlap usual caption but not replace it

Comment: Read my previous comment again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155762/discussion-between-aerosun-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0):

You have probably added some theme based styling along with your r, r1 and r2 references. I'd suggest you look for a way to build Ribbon without overriding default styling.

Comment: No, I created just a new WPF solution - and all modification you can see in the first post.